# Get specific item in model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've created a new ember project and connected it to firebase. I'm retrieving all posts fine, and displaying all posts fine, but I want to display just a single post.

I'm using ember v1.13.11

Model - app/models/post.js :

```js
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

let {
  Model,
  attr
} = DS;

export default Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  createdDate: attr('date'),
  text: attr('string'),
  imgURL: attr('string')
});
```

Route - app/routes/index.js:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
 model(){
  return this.store.findAll('post');
 }
});
```

template - app/templates/index.hbs:

```html
{{#each model as |post|}}
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  {{post.title}}
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
 <p>{{post.text}}</p>
 <br />
 <img src="{{post.imgURL}}">
 </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

This all works fine. However I was to display a specific post. I thought this would work, but I was wrong.

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      {{post.1.title}}
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     <p>{{post.1.text}}</p>
     <br />
     <img src="{{post.1.imgURL}}">
     </div>
    </div>

// OR

<div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      {{post.[1].title}}
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     <p>{{post.[1].text}}</p>
     <br />
     <img src="{{post.[1].imgURL}}">
     </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want a single specific post you should modify your model to query for it `return this.store.find('post', postId);`

Answer (score 1):

you got many options here is one doing it in the route

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('post');
},

setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set('post', model.get('firstObject'));
}
```

That wil prepare the controller with just one post

another option is in the controller create a computed atribute

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default BaseController.extend({
  onePost: Ember.computed('posts',function(){
    return this.get('posts.firstObject');
  })
}
```

and in your handlbars template reference that onePost

```
{{onePost.title}}
```

I think i like this option better

@OllieT Sorry i thought you had fixed it already, the computed goes in your component, you can put computed attributes in the model too but this is not what you want right now. So just add the computed property to where you recieve your model component or controller and then you should be able to make it appear. Your 'model' is what goes in the `return this.get('putYourModelHere')` to clearit out a bit you can do  `return this.get('putYourModelHere').get('firstObject')` which is the same as `return this.get('putYourModelHere.firstObject')` or even put {{posts.firstObject}} in your old template and you ar good to go

Comment: Would my template stay the same? (with the each tags),

Also I thought controllers are going to be deprecated? or is this a different thing?

Comment: `model.get('firstObject')` instead of `model.objectAt(0)` and there is no need to use `setupController` a computed property is more suited for this especially since you do not return super while overriding the method preventing the model property from being set on the controller.

Comment: So if we are talking of the second option (ember.computed) then being a component would be the same, and you can avoid using the each since its a single value, thought thats what you wanted, you can even hava both all posts and a single post ;). As I mentioned in my answer and seem Kitler agrees I would favor the computed option

Comment: @OllieT controllers haven't been deprecated, they have been ["repurposed"](http://locks.svbtle.com/controllers-are-dead-long-life-controllers)

Comment: @kitler  controllers have absolutely been deprecated. Routable components will be able to fill a very similar role as controllers but Ember.controller and Ember.arrayController are both 100% deprecated

From the docs: ARRAYCONTROLLER

Just like Ember.ObjectController, Ember.ArrayController will be removed in Ember 2.0 for the same reasons mentioned in 1.11's ObjectController deprecation.

Comment: @Kitler I can't seem to get option 2 to work. I have created the controller, and got temporary properties to appear in the template, so I know that is working. But im still having trouble to getting {{onePost.title}} to appear.

is the first parameter I put into the computed function my model?

Comment: @Andrew Any idea how I should be fixing my problem then? Perhaps using a component?

Comment: @Andrew Do not confuse object/array controllers with [Ember.Controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwb3HvjpG3o), it has in no way been deprecated nor removed, routable components are meant to replace it but until then controllers are here to stay, give [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwb3HvjpG3o) very interesting talk by Chris Thoburn a listen to understand what I meant by repurposed.

Comment: @OllieT Sorry i thought you had fixed it already, the computed goes in your component, you can put computed attributes in the model too but this is not what you want right now.  So just add the computed property to where you recieve your model component or controller and then you should be able to make it appear. Your 'model' is what goes in the ```return this.get('putYourModelHere')``` for you to understand it better you can do return ```this.get('putYourModelHere').get('firstObject')```

Comment: @Sudakatux I have got the first option working, but the post doesn't render in the view then I first load the app. If I change view and then come back again, it'll appear. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @Sudakatux Okay so, in my app/controllers/index.js iI should have: 
` import Ember from 'ember';

export default BaseController.extend({
  onePost: Ember.computed('MyModelHere',function(){
    return this.get('myModelHere.firstObject');
  })
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the firstObject method in a template.

So if you have a controller whose model is a bunch of posts and you want to display the title of the first of those posts, in the template for that controller you could write:

```
{{model.firstObject.title}}
```

Usually though if you are in route like `/posts` and you want to see the data for a post with id 1 you would transition to the route `/posts/1` and in the route set the model for that route as the post with the id from the url's id parameter ie in the `posts.show route` something like

```
model: function (params) {
 return this.get('store').find('post', params.id)
}
```

and then in the template you now just reference

```
{{model.title}}
```

Comment: Well model.firstObject.title works. However my end goal it to have say post1 and or PostX all on the same template. It could be Post3 or Post7..
So would having the post route to posts/1 wouldn't do this right. 

And I don't this {{model.objectAt[1]/.title}} works either..